# How can i solve this exercixe with String.prototype?

Tags: javascript

[image]

How can i create this to console log like this?

```
String.prototype.sheldonize = function () {
  return `knock ${this}`
}

'Penny'.sheldonize(3)
```

I have this code at the moment, but I dont know how to repeat knock more times

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the repeat method to establish a number of 'knocks' in the line and to establish how many times the line should repeat

```js
String.prototype.sheldonize = function (repeats) {
  const line = `${'knock '.repeat(repeats)}${this}, `.repeat(repeats)
  return `${line.substring(0,line.length-2)}.`;
}

console.log('Penny'.sheldonize(3));
```

Comment: It's unlikely in this case for obvious reasons but if you're adding methods to a prototype its always a good idea to wrap the code in a check: `if (!('sheldonize' in String.prototype)) {...}`.

Comment: Close. You need create an array of knock phrases and then `join(", ")`. Otherwise, this will end with a `,` instead of `.`

Comment: Or just use _substring_, remove the last two characters and add the dot at the end.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `For` Loop and `repeat` method

```js
String.prototype.sheldonize = function(count) {
  let ans = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ans += "knock ";
  }
  ans = `${ans}${this}, `.repeat(count)
  ans = ans.substring(0, ans.length - 2) + "."
  return ans;
}

console.log('Penny'.sheldonize(3))
console.log('Penny'.sheldonize(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and on each iteration up to `n - 1` add the string to it, finally joining it up and returning the string from the function.

```js
// If you're adding to a prototype it's always best
// to double check to see if the method already exists
// no matter (in this case) how unlikely
if (!('sheldonize' in String.prototype)) {
  String.prototype.sheldonize = function (n) {
 
    // Create the array
    const out = [];

    // Create the string
    const knock = 'knock '.repeat(n);
    
    // Loop until `n - 1` has been reached
    // pushing the string into the array
    // on each iteration
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      out.push(`${knock}${this}`);
    }

    // Finally return the joined array
    return out.join(', ');
  }
}

console.log('Penny'.sheldonize(3));
console.log('Penny'.sheldonize(2));
console.log('John'.sheldonize(4));
```

Additional documentation

- [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)